# How to import wsdl dynamically thru custome code in UFT-API

Tags: wsdl, hp-uft, uft-api

I'm new to UFT-API and working on a project. This is the scenario, i have a data table that in excel format which have three (3) columns, WSDL, SOAP_REQUEST and CHECKPOINTS. I will be looping in this excel data, each loop, i need to import new wdsl, load new request and check the checkpoints. Right now i'm just starting this project and i don't know how to import wsdl dynamically thru custom code.

Is this scenario doable?

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create OnBeforeExecuteStepEvent and try with the below code

this.StServiceCallActivity4.TransportProtocol.SOAPProperties.EndpointAddress = "";

Ex : this.StServiceCallActivity4.TransportProtocol.SOAPProperties.EndpointAddress = "https://abc";